# How to calculate months and day in formula field?

Tags: formula

For EX: i have start date and end date , if i give start date 1/11/2016 and End date as 15/12/2016 then formula field should display 1.15 which means 1 month 15 days

Comment: how come .15 means 15 days?

Comment: yes  your correct  15 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text(MONTH( DATEVALUE( hi1__Enddate__c) )-MONTH(  DATEVALUE(hi1__Start_date__c ))) + '.' + Text(DAY( DATEVALUE(hi1__Enddate__c ))+1-day( DATEVALUE(hi1__Start_date__c) ))

Answer (score 0):

```
TEXT(MONTH(end_date__c)-MONTH(start_date__c)) + '.' + TEXT(DAY(end_date__c)+1-day(start_date__c))
```

You'd also want to throw some if statements to handle 0's, blanks, put some validation rules in to make sure end date is after start date, etc. but that's the general gist of it.

Comment: Thanks above answer works fine but small correction

Comment: Text(MONTH( DATEVALUE( hi1__Enddate__c) )-MONTH(  DATEVALUE(hi1__Start_date__c ))) + '.' + Text(DAY( DATEVALUE(hi1__Enddate__c ))+1-day( DATEVALUE(hi1__Start_date__c) ))

Comment: Why are you storing your dates as strings...